# Question about increasing, differentiable, strictly convex real function where either there is a (counter-)example, or Darboux Theorem probably helps

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, convex-analysis, examples-counterexamples, mean-value-theorem

For any increasing, differentiable, strictly convex real function $f: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R},\ $ by the [mean value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem) and the nature of $f,$ there exists a unique $\ \mu\in (a,b)\ $ such that $f'(\mu) = \frac{f(b) - f(a)}{b - a}.$

I have an example of a increasing, differentiable, strictly convex real function $f: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R},\ $ that also has the property that $f'(\mu) = \frac{f(b) - f(a)}{b - a}\implies \mu \in \left(a, \frac{a+b}{2}\right),\ $ namely $f(x) = x^{3/2}$ on $[0,100].$

My question is, is there an example of a increasing, differentiable, strictly convex real function $f: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R},\ $ that also has the property that $f'(\eta) = \frac{f(b) - f(\mu)}{b - \mu}\implies \eta \in \left(a, \frac{a+b}{2}\right),\ $ where $\mu$ is defined as the point such that $f'(\mu) = \frac{f(b) - f(a)}{b - a}\ ?$

[image]

If the answer is no, then I guess [Darboux Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis)) is relevant to prove that no such function exists (but I have no idea how to do this). I imagine a (counter)-example does exist and I am not being creative enough in my attempts to come up with one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f$ defined by $g(x)=1+9e^{-x}$ is strictly convex, differientiable, not increasing but $f(x)=9x+g(x)$ is and seems to be an example with $a=0$, $b=10$.  I find $\mu=\ln(10)-\ln(-e^{-10})\approx 2.3$ and $\eta$ such that $f'(\eta)=\frac{f(b)-f(\mu)}{b-\mu}$ is less than $\frac{a+b}{2}$ as $f'(\eta)<f'(5)$ which is less computation to check as it stands to $\mu>10+e^{-5}+\frac{e^{-5}-e^{5}}{10}$ the right member being approx. $-4.8$

Comment: $g(x)$ does not need the $+1.$ i.e. $g(x) = 9e^{-x}$ is fine.

Comment: You also don't need the factor of $9.$ If $f(x):= x+e^{-x},\ $ on $\ [0, 100],\ $ I get $\ \mu = \ln 100 = 4.605\ldots,\ $ and then $\ \eta = 9.16\ldots < 50.$

Comment: I thought the function would look something like $x+e^{-x}$ does, but I couldn't think of $x+e^{-x}$ specifically, so thanks.